# Liferay: how to get ddmContentModel by json-ws

Tags: json, content-management-system, liferay

I've managed to get the ddl structure by

```
http://localhost:8090/api/jsonws/ddmstructure/get-structures/group-id/10184
```

To get the param groupId I've used:

```
http://localhost:8090/api/jsonws/group/get-user-group/company-id/10157/user-id/10639
```

To find the userId:

```
http://localhost:8090/api/jsonws/user/get-user-by-email-address/company-id/10157/email-address/test%40liferay.com
```

The companyId is from:

```
http://localhost:8090/api/jsonws/company/get-company-by-virtual-host/virtual-host/localhost
```

Please, could you point me to any resources describing the Json web service in more details.

I didn't find any docs the defines the form of the orderByComparator /ddlrecordset/search.

I would like to get the content of the dynamical list. I've found that data is contained in ddmcontent table - corresponding java file is \portal-service\src\com\liferay\portlet\dynamicdatamapping\model\DDMContentModel.java. How to do that?

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the below articles: The second one uses the skinny JSON provider to get the list of DDL records from a DDL Record Set

https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/json-web-services

https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/invoking-services-using-skinny-json-provider